# How to create PDF outline

Tags: xetex, pdf, plain-tex

According to [the PDF reference (PDF document, 9.4MB)](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf), one can create an outline for the document; a visual table of contents for the viewer application which enables the user to jump to the page for the outline entry. It is my  understanding that the LaTeX [hyperref](/questions/tagged/hyperref) package creates these outline entries.

I would like to know how it works under the hood, so to speak. I have tried the following code:

```
\def\subject#1\par{% other stuff...
  \special{pdf: out 1 << /Title (#1) /Dest [ @thispage /FitH @ypos ] >>}}
```

But this doesn't seem to create anything in the outline. Can you tell what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recommend using the [`navigator`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/navigator) package, which works with LaTeX, ConTeXt and Plain TeX. Outlines are created with

```
\outline[<options>]{<level>}[<name>]{<title>}
```

where `<options>` is fairly self explanatory, `<level>` is a number representing how deep in the hierarchy the outline is, `<name>` is an internal name used to refer to the point in the document at which the outline is located (for links, etc.) and `<title>` is the name of the outline.

Comment: Thank you; I already understand a little more of the `navigator` documentation. If you have time, a complete MWE would add to the value of this answer, since `navigator-doc.tex` is rather opaque for those who have not been initiated into the mysteries of `texapi` and `YaX`.

Comment: For ConTeXt, outlines can be created [easier and automatically](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249840/26348).

Answer (score 5):

There are several problems from (plain or primitive) TeX point of view when creating PDF outlines.

- The primitive level depends on used machine. For example, in pdfTeX, you have to use `\pdfoutline` primitive but when you plan to process dvi to pdf (for example in XeTeX), then there is `\special{pdf:outline...}`. It means that you need to implement a low level macro (for example `\insertoutline`), which is defined differently, depending on the type of postprocessing and/or TeX machine.
- It is natural for macro programmer to specify the level, which represents the deep of the PDF outline it the tree. But the primitive commands only continue the PDF specification where we have to know the number of children for each node in the tree, no the deep of this node. This implies that we need to calculate from deep-data to childrens-data in our macros. This needs two pass algorithm.
- The text in PDF outlines, PDF info etc. have to be encoded like PDF string. PDF specification mentions two possibilities: PDFdocEncoding (similar to ISO-8859-1) or UTF-16BE. The second variant needs to do conversion from internal TeX representation of text to very special encoding. This have to be done at macro level.

I have solved all these problems in my macro OPmac (for plain TeX). The problems are described from implementation point of view in detail in the technical documentation of OPmac `opmac-d.pdf`. But this is only in Czech language, sorry.

Comment: About the first point: I am only concerned in XeTeX, so maybe much simpler. About your second bullet point: In the sources for `navigator.tex`, there is a comment: "**So much simpler because xdvipdfmx deals with children automatically; thus `\nav@processoutlines` is unnecessary.**". Please correct if I'm misinterpreting, but doesn't that mean that there would not need to be two passes with xdvipdfmx? Thanks for the third point, that was something that hadn't even crossed my mind!

Comment: @morbusg If you rely on XeTeX only then your life is much simpler. The xdvipdfmx does all things in its own working: deep-data to children-data calculation and TeX text to UTF-16BE conversion. Sorry, I didn't notify that you needs the XeTeX-only solution. My three bullets are irrelevant in such case. They are valid only if you need to create PDF outlines macros for pdfTeX or for various TeX machines.

Answer (score 3):

In [ConTeXt](http://wiki.contextgarden.net), the PDF outline is misleadingly called PDF bookmarks.
These are automatically created when using the following code snippet in the document preamble.

```
\setupinteraction[state=start] % don't forget this line!
% make chapter, section bookmarks visible when opening document
\placebookmarks[chapter,section,subsection][chapter,section]
\setupinteractionscreen[option=bookmark]
\starttext
```

More details can be found over at [contextgarden.net](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/PDF_Bookmarks_and_Headers).